# Should a backend api store layout information?

Tags: sql, rest, soa

I need to create a system to store and serve information about survey questions. Given a variety of questions, field types and field arrangments, I need to serve the data needed by the front end to display the fields.

One of my big concerns is layout information. I'm not sure all the ways the fields can be arranged. At a minimum, I need to support things like two text fields appearing on 1 line, with a third on the next line. Or 6 multiple choice answers arranged in 2 columns of 3 rows.

Is it appropriate to store this layout information in my database, and to serve it with the question/field data? I think these are my 3 options. Any thoughts on these options would be very helpful, or suggestions for other things to consider:

- I could store indicators that the question uses a column layout, and give each field hints as to what row/column it is in.
- I could store something like CSS or mustache templates to define the layout.
- I could leave this entirely to the front end. I could return the survey data and expect the front end to handle any layout concerns

Comment: Having ran into this a few times, XML is a great format for this. It's at this point probably an unpopular suggestion, but I've had to make the same decision a few times and it fits the bill extremely well.

Comment: You can transpose the same structure you would get with XML onto something like JSON but it would be far more painful.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer/advice i would give is no. If you put any layout information in the database you will make it very hard to build new functionality, extend your product offering in the future, support multiple front ends (mobile, progressive web app, main website) and perform redesigns in the future.

I would go with option C. Leave it to the front end. You can easily store the 'type' of question which may map to a template in the front end maybe, this will allow the different front ends to render that type of template as the design needs. And will allow you to easily evolve the design in the future, the last thing you want if you desire to do a redesign is to need DB update scripts to try and 'fix' css and display data.

Obviously i lack the full picture of what you are trying to achieve, the road map of your product and your future ideas, but i honestly cant think of a scenario where storing css in the DB would be a good idea.

I hope you find this useful, I would be keen to hear how you decide to progress with this.